# Field Collection Content not showing on published page

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm wondering if anyone has had this problem with the Field Collection Module.  I needed to add two fields to a field collection that appears in a particular content type.  Simple:  Title and Subtitle.  I added the fields with no problem and they appear in the content type when creating a new node. But, once the node is published, the two fields (Title and Subtitle) don't appear.  I have some screen captures so you can get a better idea of what I am doing:
[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3][image: 4]

Where I have "Test Title", should show up below "Test Registration" and above the blue boxes.

I looked at a few videos and didn't see any other steps to get these items to show.  Has anyone dealt with this before or have any suggestions?

Thanks